# Javascript shorthand syntax explanation

Tags: javascript

I gone through this syntax in my project. Can I get the explanation for this code please?

```
 // Handles focus on error title.
 var error = $('#consentError')[0];
 error && error.focus();
```

Is this the shorthand syntax for if() condition.

Comment: basically evaluate second only when the first one is true. In your case error.focus() will be executed only when there is some value in error

Comment: $('#consentError') is a Jquery selector. It selects elements with the id of 'consentError'. I dont think  indexer is needed though. This node is passed to the error variable. After that it checks that if error has a value and is not null then focus that node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code is equivalent to

```
var error = $('#consentError')[0];
if (error) {
  error.focus();
}
```

The `if` version is definitely easier to read and comprehend at a glance. Using the `&&` method creates an unused expression, which is weird and is [often forbidden](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-expressions) by linters.

But jQuery has an even better way to achieve this - just call `focus` on the jQuery collection, and it'll call `.focus()` on the native element, if there is such an element (and if there isn't one, it just won't do anything - it won't throw).

```
$('#consentError').focus();
```

Comment: In this case the variable `error` should not return an array

Comment: jQuery doesn't return arrays, it returns jQuery objects. But even if multiple elements match the selector, it would still call `focus()` on the first matching element (if there is such an element).